# CSHTML check box not changing when deslected

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I ma using the code below to get a check box, but the values of the check box does not change. any idea why this would be the case

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
```

Comment: The checkbox is not checking/unchecking or IsActive is not changing in your model?

Comment: it being check and changing but not when it has been checked

Comment: one the data has been read fromthe database and been checked it doe not chnage the state of the object after thios

Answer (score 0):

instead of editorfor use this

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor
```